# How do I mimic Java Springs @PathVariable using Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
user_dict = {}


class User(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        user_id = 0

    def get(self):
        return jsonify(user_dict[id])

api.add_resource(User, "/user")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The idea is that when a GET request is made to /user/1, then the get method returns that key/value pair of the `user_dict`. How do I do path variables in Python? Please assume that the dictionary is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask uses [`<variable_name>` or `<converter:variable_name>` placeholders](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/lastest/quickstart/#variable-rules) in URL path registrations.

This is used in the examples shown in the Flask-Restful [Quickstart documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing):

```py
class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')
```

Here `<string:todo_id>` is a path variable, passed to the `TodoSimple.get()` and `TodoSimple.put()` methods as an argument.

Flask-Restful otherwise assumes a general familiarity with Flask's patterns, I strongly recommend you read through at least the Flask [Quickstart document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/), and I recommend you also work through the [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/tutorial/), if nothing else.

For your specific example, if user ids are always integers, use:

```
class User(Resource):
    def get(self, user_id):
        return jsonify(user_dict[user_id])

api.add_resource(User, "/user/<int:user_id>")
```

Comment: It looks like POST needs to be in a separate class. This is a lot different than Java Spring. Thank you for the link to the documentation.

Comment: @juice: yes, the view classes that Flask-Resources uses are *per route*. In a RESTful API creating new resources use a POST to a base URL, while access to individual resources access the base URL plus identifier, so those are separate routes and separate views.